# Get value and pass to parameter datables

Tags: datatables, datetimepicker

So I have datetimepicker. And I have datatable like the following code

```
    var table = $("#tbllogvisitor");
    var target = table.attr('data-table');
    var date = $("#datetimepicker3").data("date");

    var oTable = table.on( 'processing.dt', function ( e, settings, processing ){
        if (processing) {
            $(this).find('tbody').addClass('load1 csspinner');
        } else{
            $(this).find('tbody').removeClass('load1 csspinner');
        };
    }).DataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "paging": false,
        "filter": false,
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "ordering": false,
        "ajax": {
            "url" : "../ajax/datatable",
            "type": "POST",
            "data" :{
                       target: function() { return target },
                       tanggal: function() { return date }
                    }
        }
    });
```

Well is working, and then I wanna trigger datetimepicter if I'm changing my datetimepicter value with the following code :

```
$("#datetimepicker3").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    oTable.ajax.reload();
});
```

But the paramater variable of datetimepicker still not change at all, still same at first time. How do Ii pass my value datetimepicker and reload the datatable?

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: can you add code of datatable and datepicker to jsfiddle?

Comment: @yash no i cant, cause i'm using ajax file, did you see my question??  I'm allready put code with ajax file.. if i'm put into jsfiddle it will not working.